# POST: 500 Internal Server Error from Messenger Bot in laravel

Tags: laravel, ngrok, facebook-chatbot

I setup my Webhok by Ngrok URL for my Facebook page, and I applied all of the requirements for the Messenger Platform, but when I send the messages to my Facebook page I encounter the following error:

```
POST /Facebook_Messenger_Token 500 Internal Server Error
```

and in routs file in Laravel I use Get and Post functions as follow:

```
Route::get('Facebook_Messenger_Token', 'MessengerController@index');
Route::post('Facebook_Messenger_Token', 'MessengerController@index');
```

When I send the messages I get the following error in storage/app.logs/laravel:

```
[2020-06-08 18:44:21] local.ERROR: Undefined variable: id {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: id at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\AzadApp\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\MessengerController.php:17)
[stacktrace]
```

my public function index:

```
public function index()
    {
        // here we can verify the webhook.
        // i create a method for that.
        $this->verifyAccess();

        $user    = json_decode($this->getUser($id)); --this is line 17
        $input   = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $id      = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
        $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];

        $response = [
            'recipient'     =>  ['id'   => $id ],
            'message'       =>  ['text' => "Thanks for watching {$user->first_name} {$user->last_name}! :)"]
        ];

        $this->sendMessage($response);
    }
```

Please support and thanks.

Comment: Seems like csrf issue, did you except this routes from csrf???

Comment: First welcome to Stackoverflow, you should edit the question and change the following: 1) instead of a screenshot copy and paste the output as text.
2) you are only showing the routes you should also show MessengerController (index function)
now csrf error is 419 page expired as far as i know 
a 500 error need debugging, so either you can look in storage/logs/laravel.log and past the last error here if you couldn't solve it yourself or show us the controller method for us to check if there is any obvious error in the code.

Comment: @TalhaF. No, how can I do this?

Comment: @George thank you very much for your support,
i edited my post so please recheck

Comment: Hi again Azad the error you posted is very descriptive, it says that id is not defined on `MessengerController line 17` for sure it's the index function i asked you to post it's code earlier. please copy `public function index` from `MessengerController` and past it in your question

Comment: Copy the entire function please

Comment: @George done dear, Is that clear enough?

Comment: yes @Azad since you are new to SO please review this post on how to ask a good question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . regarding the error 
`$id` in `json_decode($this->getUser($id))` should be defined before you use it on line 17  so moving line 19 before line 17 should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The $id is being defined on line 19 (that is after line 17). in order to use it on

`$user    = json_decode($this->getUser($id));`

you should place the above line after line 19

`$id      = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];`

do not move line 19 up (as i said in my comment) instead move line 17 down since

`$id      = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];`

is using $input that is defined before.

all you have to do is move line 17 under line 19.

so the full function now should look like this:

```
public function index()
    {
        // here we can verify the webhook.
        // i create a method for that.
        $this->verifyAccess();


        $input   = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        $id      = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'];
        $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text'];
        $user    = json_decode($this->getUser($id));

        $response = [
            'recipient'     =>  ['id'   => $id ],
            'message'       =>  ['text' => "Thanks for watching {$user->first_name} {$user->last_name}! :)"]
        ];

        $this->sendMessage($response);
    }
```